# Actual values of content tags in facebook graph API

Tags: facebook-graph-api

Requesting for content tags on a video returns a list of numerical strings in Facebook Graph API. Is there a reference for looking up these values for an actual tag in strings? The numbers returned don't seem to be Graph objects (greened out in graph api explorer - see image 1). I tried a simple get request with the object id, but it returns an error (image 2). Is it a permissions issue or something else?

[Image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a6kqo.png)

[Image 2 - looking up first content tag in above result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IIGtz.png)

Comment: Documentation says you can use the API search endpoint with `type=adinterest` to find ids; not sure whether they want you to be able to perform the look-up in the other direction.

Comment: @CBroe yeah I want to look up the other way. Reading content_tags of a video gives me the IDs (eg. "1023278094369263") and I want to see what string this corresponds to (eg. "Genetics&Genomics"). My objective is to use these tags to group videos, and do group-wise analysis (views, shares etc).

Comment: Hm, the IDs the search endpoint returns seem to allow to look up the corresponding object ... so either that ID you got there is for something else, or maybe not all tags are public …?

Comment: The tag was entered on the page while creating the video-post (one of Facebook's tags, not a custom-tag). So it was not created using an api or type=adinterest. But it still returns a tag id, when I look it up. It's just that tag ID is not a searchable graph object. By the way, if it's my own page, should I be able to see non-public tags as well?